# header=FALSE "Levels" in read.table()

Tags: r

In order to have the header labels as entries in the matrix rather than names, I used read.table with the argument header=FALSE.

When I call header entries as elements, I get something along the lines of the following:

TCGA_20_0987_01A_02R_0434_01
21199 Levels: 10.0039251940782 10.0057778066803 ... TCGA_20_0987_01A_02R_0434_01

Now, the first value (TCGA_20...) is what I want. Where do the "Levels" entries come from, what are they, and how can I avoid them so that only the header label appears as the matrix element?

Answer (score 5):

If you specify header=FALSE the first line is read in as data. If the first line is all text, then the variables will all be factor variables ( .... not what you want.) Try with header=TRUE. I suspect your first line in that file are column names. If you can paste in the first few lines from that text file it will be more clear what is going on. There are methods to force a particular column to be read as a specified class but we need to see what is needed first.

Comment: I need header=FALSE so that the header elements are read in as entries in the matrix rather than headers as such.

Comment: Then ... please ... show some data. You cannot have columns that are mixtures of numeric and text. R simply will not allow that.